# How to model compound key in Hibernate?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot

I am modeling a model class in java with Hibernate. But the table in the DB already exists and I want to use it.

The problem is that the table do not have an ID. Besides, the worse is that the tuple in the table are formed by four columns and their combination makes a "kind of identification/ID". Also, the columns are not FK to others tables.

Is there a way to model this with java, hibernate, and so on, without "fix/alter" the table?

Thanks

Comment: You mean: the table does not have a [Primary Key](https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_primarykey.asp)?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes - I think the OP means the table has a compound primary key, and not a single column ID.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define your class with an @EmbeddedId Example:

Your Entity that already exists :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTITY_EXAMPLE")
public class EntityExample {

    // this is your new class Embeddable
    @EmbeddedId
    private EntityExampleId id;

    //other fields


    //geters y seters
      //////////////////////////

 }
```

And have to create other Class @Embeddable that contains your 4 columns of your composite ID

```
@Embeddable
public class EntityExampleId implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "COLUMN1", nullable = false)
    private Integer col1; 

    @Column(name = "COLUMN2", nullable = false)
    private Integer col2; 

    @Column(name = "COLUMN3", nullable = false)
    private Date col3;

    @Column(name = "COLUMN4", nullable = false)
    private Date col4;

    //geters y seters
   //////////////////////////

}
```

For more info see the references

- [reference 1](https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-composite-primary-key-example/)
- [reference 2](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-composite-primary-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)
- [reference 3](https://medium.com/@bhagyajayashani/composite-key-handling-using-embeddedid-annotation-in-spring-boot-java-67c29da9d119)

Comment: Thank you. I make it works. But it just works after I set the hashCode and the Equals methods to be built just with the ID

Comment: I'm sorry I assumed that. Please mark aswer as a correct @ViniciusdeAndrade 
 best regards